# Razor MVC, where to put global variables that's accessible across master page, partiview and view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hello Razor MVC Gurus:

**Newbie question.**

Background. I have a custom IIdentity that is set in an HttpModule before it gets to controller & views. To use it, i have to do

```
   MyIdentity myIdentity = (MyIdentity)((GenericPrincipal)context.User).Identity;
   MyComplexUser user = myIdentity.User;
   //user.name //user.location //user.username  //etc
```

The problem is, I use the object in different places such as

- master layout
- Some sub level nested layouts
- Some partialviews
- Some views

It really depends on what properties of "MyComplexUser" object the views need.

Currently, in the views, I have to do this really complicated casting to get to a property. For instance, if I want the "Name" of the user, I need to do

@(((MyComplexUser)(((MyIdentity)((GenericPrincipal)context.User).Identity).User)).Name)

I suppose I could put it in the controllers and then populate the ViewBag with a ViewBag.MyUser property, but then

1. I don't like to use ViewBag. I prefer strongly typed objects
2. If I use a strongly typed object ("MyUser") for views, then I have to popular all those models with a "MyUser" property. Feels a bit dirty? As I like to keep my models clean and be specific to the views they are involved with.  Besides, it gets unnecessarily repetitive.
3. In places like master_layout.cshtml or partialviews, how do you access "MyUser"  if I put them in a controller?
4. Use RenderAction and build partialviews for each User property is an overkill?

Thanks. Again, I'm a newbie at MVC 4, any suggestion is greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I have a similar scenario. I'll post it as a comment, if you prefer I may add as an answer: all my controllers inherit from a `BaseController`, which I've written. In this base class, I've wired up events of the lifecycle, such as `ExecuteCore`. I also use filters for things like this. On the view side, all my viewmodels inherit from `BaseVM`, where I place common properties, such as messages to the user, username and so on.

Comment: @AndreCalil, could you explain a bit more? So you are populating a base model from the base controller, is that it? 

I'm not getting the part where you use filters, could you give an example? 

Also, if you populated the common properties in the base model, how do you use it in master layout page? do \\@Model BaseVM and then \\@Model.UserName?

Thanks

Comment: There you go. And I don't think that this is a newbie question at all

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll explain a similar solution that works pretty well for me. With small changes, I *believe* that it will work for you (and others, hopefully) as well.

Basically, we'll be using **inheritance**.

## Controllers

Let's create a custom base controller, such as

```
public class BaseController : Controller
```

and let's change our controllers to inherit from it, as

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
```

## Models (ViewModels, I say)

You probably have lots of classes inside your Models folder, right? They act as DTOs from the controller to the views, right²?
If you answered *yes* for both, then keep reading.

Let's create a base model class, such as `public class BaseVM`, and let's change our models to inherit from it, like `public class HomeIndex : BaseVM`

**Important:** your layout file (`_Layout` or whatsoever) must be strongly typed to `BaseVM` or a child of it.

## The hook

Now that everything's beautifuly typed, let's use the request pipeline in our favor.
At `BaseController`, you'll add a method that looks like this:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is ViewResultBase)//Gets ViewResult and PartialViewResult
    {
        object viewModel = ((ViewResultBase)filterContext.Result).Model;

        if (viewModel != null && viewModel is BaseVM)
        {
            BaseVM baseVM = viewModel as BaseVM;

            baseVM.MyIdentity = (MyIdentity)((GenericPrincipal)context.User).Identity;
            //and so on...
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);//this is important!
}
```

`OnActionExecuted` is called **after** the execution of the action but **before** the view rendering. That's exactly what we want.

I hope you got it already. =)

Comment: Got it! Thanks Andre. BaseController + BaseModel makes sense:) Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: Nice solution - finally an easy way to pass objects to all the views without having to use ViewBag.

Comment: How do you make _Layout strongly typed?

Comment: @Hcabnettek its model should be the `BaseVM` model. In that way, the model for every child page would fit the _Layout as well

Comment: @AndreCalil yes this worked perfect! Very nice implementation sir. I didn't realize all I had to do was `model BaseViewModel`. I just didn't think of it for some reason.

Comment: @Hcabnettek That's nice, I'm glad that it worked. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @AndreCalil, fantastic stuff! Very useful approach.

Comment: @AndreCalil would you mind having a look at a follow up question I have on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915990/mvc-basecontroller-and-basemodel-to-ensure-that-values-are-available-to-all-view

Comment: Nice! Btw you don't need the null check. 
`if (viewModel != null && viewModel is BaseVM)`
is the same as 
`if (viewModel is BaseVM)`