# Maintaining input control state in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

In the app I'm working on the administrator has the ability to select a customer to work with in a drop down list. Thing is that there are a large number of views that the administrator can go through and each time they'd have to select the customer again. In webforms this was rather easy... store it in a Session variable and reset it when another page loads.

MVC not so much. I seem to be stuck at the point where I pass this value to the view from the controller. We are storing the value in a Session variable which we access using a base controller like this:

```
MyController.CurrentUser.CurrentCustomerId
```

The question I can't solve is how I pass this value to a partial view. The customer selector tool is in a partial view which is added to pages that need it.

I thought of using the ViewBag, but that means that in every single action in my controllers that requires this value I would have to add:

```
ViewBag.CurrentCustomerId = CurrentUser.CurrentCustomerId;
```

And even then I'm not sure if the ViewBag data is carried through to the partial view. I think it is.

Seems like there should be a more efficient way to do this and still abide by MVC rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andre Calil provided a very good solution for carrying user information between controllers and views and I ended up using this approach.

See his answer at the following link: [Razor MVC, where to put global variables that's accessible across master page, partiview and view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986251/razor-mvc-where-to-put-global-variables-thats-accessible-across-master-page-p)