# MVC BaseController and BaseModel to ensure that values are available to all views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is a question about a solution provided by @Andre Calil in the following SO 
[Razor MVC, where to put global variables that's accessible across master page, partiview and view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986251/razor-mvc-where-to-put-global-variables-thats-accessible-across-master-page-p)

I'm using Andre's approach and have a slight problem: 
My _Layout is strongly typed as BaseModel and my view is strongly typed as AccountModel which inherits from BaseModel.

**Problem is**: if I return a view with no model i.e. return View() then I get an exception. It's caused because the BaseController OnActionExecuted event is checking if the model provided is null as in:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is ViewResultBase)//Gets ViewResult and PartialViewResult
    {
        object viewModel = ((ViewResultBase)filterContext.Result).Model;

        if (viewModel != null && viewModel is MyBaseModel)
        {
            MyBaseModel myBase = viewModel as MyBaseModel;
            myBase.Firstname = CurrentUser.Firstname; //available from base controller
        }
    }
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);//this is important!
}
```

The model is null so this scenario won't always work. My next step was to make sure I always pass a model into a view even if it's an empty BaseModel object. Problem with that is that I get the following exception:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyNamespace.BaseModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyNamespace.AccountModel'.
```

Two points that I need to clarify:

1. I thought this would work because AccountModel is a sub class of BaseModel?
2. If the model is null in the code above, is there another way that I can inject a model into each view so that I can avoid having to refactor all my code to include return View(BaseModel.Empty)?

Comment: As an aside, have you looked at using a Profile provider for this?

Comment: @ChrisHardie we used the Profile provider initially, but it wouldn't make sense in all cases because there's more information that needs to be extracted out of various places that make up the context of the request/response. At times this may include input from the user

Comment: @Jacques A null viewmodel (such as `View()`) should work fine. Could you add to the question the error you're getting?

Comment: @Jacques Sorry for the flood, another point: if you want the choice of sending null viewmodels to your view, you must ensure that they support it. That is, at your `_Layout` and child view you must test if the model is null before using it. Otherwise, you'll run into `NullReferenceException` from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at custom razor views as described by Phil Haacked in this article:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx

So basically in your BaseController you would set up a public variable that will be fetched on every request in the base controller's Initialize event (in my case it is the instance of User):

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   public User AppUser;

   protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
   {
       base.Initialize(requestContext);
       AppUser = _userService.GetUser(id);
       ViewBag.User = AppUser;
   }
}
```

So now you have a variable which can be accessed by any controller which inherits from the base controller. The only thing left to do is to figure out how to use this variable inside your view. This is where the article I linked above will help you. By default all your views are generated from System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage. However you can make a custom implementation of this class by doing the following:

```
namespace YourApplication.Namespace
{
   public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
   {
      private User _appUser;

      public User AppUser
      {
         get
         {
            try
            {
                _appUser = (User)ViewBag.User;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _appUser = null;
            }
            return _appUser;
         }
      }
   }

   public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class
   {
      private User _appUser;

      public User AppUser
      {
          get
          {
              try
              {
                 _appUser = (User)ViewBag.User;
              }
              catch (Exception)
              {
                 _appUser = null;
              }
              return _appUser;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

You have just defined a custom razor view class which has a property of user and tries to fetch that from the ViewBag.User that we setup in our base controller. The only thing left to do is to tell your app to use this class when it's trying to generate the view. You can do this by setting the following line in your VIEWS web.config file:

```
<pages pageBaseType="YourApplication.Namespace.CustomWebViewPage">
```

Now on your view you get a helper for your User property that you can use like this:

```
@AppUser
```

Please not that the pages declaration needs to go into the VIEWS web.config files not the main app web.config!

I think this is a much better solution for you since you don't have to provide the base model to all your view via the view model. View model should be reserved for what it is intended.

Comment: thanks for that. We've stripped all of this out for the moment until we get time to do a proper implementation at which point I'll get back to your suggestion.