# Access model variables in entire project MVC5 Razor - use Basecontroller to set BaseViewModel and use that in Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm a bit new to MVC5 and I was trying to use the method shown in the following answer to set global variables in the entire project:
[Razor MVC, where to put global variables that's accessible across master page, partiview and view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986251/razor-mvc-where-to-put-global-variables-thats-accessible-across-master-page-p/16987530#16987530)

My aim is to set the variables in the base controller which can be utilized by the layout page whenever a view is changed.

The problem which I am facing is as follows:
I've created a base controller which is inherited by all other controllers;

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected ViewModelBase ModelBase { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.Result is ViewResultBase)//Gets ViewResult and PartialViewResult
            {

                object viewModel = ((ViewResultBase)filterContext.Result).Model;

                if (viewModel != null && viewModel is ViewModelBase)
                {
                    ViewModelBase baseVM = viewModel as ViewModelBase;

                    ALM_APP objALM_APP = new ALM_APP();
                    objALM_APP = DalContext.getAppInformation();


                    baseVM.ApplicationName = objALM_APP.ApplicationName;
                    baseVM.AppVersion = objALM_APP.Version;
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);//this is important!
        }  
    }
```

I've then created a ViewModelBase class which is strongly typed with _Layout.cshtml

```
namespace TestProject.Models
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase
    {
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string Groups { get; set; }
        public string LoginTime { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, string> MenuList { get; set; }
    }
}

public class CommonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
}
```

In the _Layout.cshtml file I am calling viewmodelbase as follows:

```
@model TestProject.Models.ViewModelBase
```

and then I used the model attribute as following in the layout:

```
@Model.ApplicationName
```

In this case, the viewModel is always null in BaseController when filterContext.Result is typecasted to ViewResultBase:

```
object viewModel = ((ViewResultBase)filterContext.Result).Model;
```

Due to which @Model.ApplicationName is throwing a Null reference exception as follows:

"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_3t5b2o3k.dll but was not handled in user code"

I have also tried to create a new object of CommonViewModel class in the basecontroller and set the model attributes in it but to no success.

I would be grateful if I can get some help regarding this.

Comment: In order to have the filterContext.Result not null... in your Action you need to pass the model to the view. The filter runs after the action ended and before the view is showed. May be you can share the Action you are using.

Comment: @Romias, the layout (which uses viewmodelbase) and the corresponding view is called by another controller in which the following action result is called: 
`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Username, string Password)
{
 return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard.cshtml");
}
`

Comment: A Layout with a @Model line and actions not passing a model is not correct from my point of view. You could try putting that information in ViewBag... so you don't rely in models. Or try passing the model in the Index action, as a second parameter of the View() call.

Comment: Can you tell me what changes do I have to make if I want to keep using @Model in layout and set the required information in the base controller?

Comment: @Romias It kind of worked..
I've tried passing the Model as follows:
`return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard.cshtml", new CommonViewModel());`

Now I have to check whether the CommonViewModel object is persistent for one session.

Thanks a lot for the heads up! appreciated.

Comment: Even the way you are returning the view from "Index" action without a relevent Model should still throw Null reference exception, in a default MVC app having no BaseController etc infra.

Comment: This approach you are using, will make you send in every View the Model. That is why I sugested changing to the ViewBag approach. I mean, put the variables you need in ViewBag, instead of the Base model.

Comment: @SivaGopal Thank you for the heads up. I'll try not to do that next time. Still getting to grips with MVC :)

Comment: @Romias If I put the variables in ViewBag and change views will the ViewBag variables still persist on the Layout?
I tried using ViewBag initially but I was losing all ViewBag values in Layout file when changing to a different view.

Comment: Check my answer bellow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a similar approach than you in CRUD views to pass to the view flags with user permision (CanCreate, CanUpdate, etc). But in this case I know when to do it. In your case is application wide.

You can try this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;

    // IController is not necessarily a Controller
    if (controller != null)
    {
        ALM_APP objALM_APP = new ALM_APP();
        objALM_APP = DalContext.getAppInformation();

        controller.ViewBag.ApplicationName = objALM_APP.ApplicationName;
        controller.ViewBag.AppVersion = objALM_APP.Version;

     }
}
```

So, in each new Action executed, the ViewBag variables are reloaded.
If you call a PartialView, the Layout is not executed... so, no problem (the ViewBag variables are reloaded, but will not be used by Layout).

Comment: I'll give this a try with multiple views and will get back to you. Thanks!